# linear regression requirements in Bayesian stats

Tags: r, regression, bayesian, stan

In Frequentist framework when someone runs a linear model has to check the [assumptions](http://r-statistics.co/Assumptions-of-Linear-Regression.html).

There is a need to check these assumptions in Bayesian Linear Regression too?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - just because you augment the likelihood with a prior does not magically turn a wrong model into a correct one. Say your linear model is also linear in the variables, like in $y_i=\delta_0+\delta_1x_i+v_i$, but the true data-generating process contains a quadratic term, like in $y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1x_i+\beta_2x_i^2+u_i$.

No prior on the $\delta_j$ will return the nonlinear effects that you might be after for good predictions or even causal interpretations.